# Difference in variable declarations in Cocoa Class

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to iOS development and I've been seeing the following in several tutorials as well as when Xcode autogenerates code for me when subclassing one of my classes. Let's say I have the following .h and .m files

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Class : NSObject {
    NSArray *_infos;
    NSString *_context;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *infos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *context;

@end

#import "Class.h"

@implementation Class

@synthesize infos = _infos;
@synthesize context = _context;

@end
```

And then consider this which is how I would normally do it:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Class : NSObject {
    NSArray *infos;
    NSString *context;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *infos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *context;

@end

#import "Class.h"

@implementation Class

@synthesize infos;
@synthesize context;

@end
```

What is the difference? From the notation I can just infer that they're just declaring the variables as private, but how does it work? If I'm correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a silly naming convention. Use it if you want to, leave it if you don't.

The advantage is that a method argument/local variable named `context` does not conflict with the ivar `_context`. It has little to do with privacy, since you can just specify @private to make the ivars private (or just `@synthesize` them in the first place).

The disadvantage is that you have underscores everywhere, and underscores are occasionally a bit special in C (though an underscore followed by a lowercase letter is only reserved in file scope, so you *should* be fine provided the ivar starts with a lowercase letter...). Where necessary, I stick an underscore at the *end* which feels less dirty.

Sidenote: A few people use *method* names beginning with an underscore to mean "private", but this convention is [reserved by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1003829-BCIBDJCA).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the name of the ivars ("instance variables") holding the properties.